# Duplicate images being displayed in foreach loop with ACF image field

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, if-statement, foreach

I am adding a custom admin table column to a custom post type called 'program'.

I created an acf image field, that is set with a return value of array.

'program' has two posts that have a selected image each.
The other two posts have no image selected, so I have added a fallback image dynamically.

When the images are displayed in the column, they are being output twice??

[image]

When I do `print_r($selected_image)` I see it outputs two id's in the array, uppercase ID and lowercase id

[image]

I am using a foreach loop, since there are multiple images that I want to get from more than one post, so is the foreach loop creating this issue somehow? am I missing something?

Code:

```
function cpt_columns_content($column_id, $post_id) {

    $selected_image = get_field('archive_background_image');
    $size = 'xsm_thumbnail';

    if ($column_id == 'last_modified') {
        echo get_post_field('post_modified', $post_id);
    } 
    
    else if ('post_thumbs') {
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            the_post_thumbnail('xsm_thumbnail');
    } 
    
    // foreach loop to output selected acf image field image from each post
    else if (!empty($selected_image)) {
        foreach ($selected_image as $image_id) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($image_id, $size);
        }
    } 
   
    else if (!has_post_thumbnail()) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image(156, 'xsm_thumbnail');
            //echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(156, 'archive_thumbnail')[0];    
        } else { ... }
    }
}
add_action('manage_program_posts_custom_column', 'cpt_columns_content', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see it outputs two id's in the array, uppercase ID and lowercase id

That is just default WordPress behavior, it provides both versions, so that developers can use either spelling to access the id property of any post.

> When the images are displayed in the column, they are being output twice??

Because you are looping over both IDs ... and then even more stuff.

You should not be looping over `$selected_image` at all here. That is the data for *one* single file. Your current code loops over both `ID` and `id` (hence you get two images) - and would then proceed to loop over `title`, `filename` etc. That makes no sense at all, you would be passing the value `History` as an *image id* to `wp_get_attachment_image` next.

This should *just* be

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image($selected_image['id], $size);`
```

without any loops.

Comment: ohhh! I understand now, I am still quite the novice... Thank you for your swift reply.

Comment: CBroe, alternatively if I was to get a fallback image from the image directory of my theme, how can I do this without using html img tags? I have this so far: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/assets/images/geo.jpg';` but it only retrieves the url and not the image?

Comment: You can't expect much else from an image file that just lays around in your theme folder; if you wanted to use WP functionality to provide different sizes automatically, then you would need to upload it to the media library, _then_ you would get an ID that you can again use with `wp_get_attachment_image`.